# check if a checkbox inside a label is ticked or not

Tags: jquery

I have a checkbox inside a label

```
<label class="selectit"><input value="84" name="download_category[]" id="in-download_category-84" type="checkbox"> CPU, HDD, Ram</label>
```

I want to check if the checkbox is check or not without using checkbox id.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".selectit").click(function(){
            //Go and check if checkbox is check.
            //If checkbox is tick
            alert(this.Text());
        });
    });
    </script>
```

How can I do it?

Comment: I tried the same with jsfiddle.net/annamalaicse/669fsxyd Its working for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Please try this**

```
$(".selectit").click(function() {
  if ($(this).find('input[type=checkbox]').is(":checked")) {
    alert($(".selectit").text());
  }
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Rino_Raj/8TT4p/1588/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".selectit").click(function(){
          if($(this).prop('checked') == true) {
               //checkbox is checked
           }
           else
           {
               //checkbox is not checked
           }
        });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use several ways to find the check box. For instance you can use `$('.selectit').find('input:checked').length` which will be greater than 0 if the checkbox is checked. You can also use `change` function on checkbox and read the value `onChange`.

Personally I would avoid label click function as it is confusing whether the click should occur before the checkbox gets checked/unchecked or after.

See the [jsFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/taleebanwar/mz72kxp2/). Here I'm checking the state of checkbox on button click event.

```
$('#checkit').click(function(){
    if($('.selectit > input:checked').length){
        alert($('.selectit').text())
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 <label class="selectit"><input value="84" name="download_category[]" id="in-download_category-84" type="checkbox" id='a'> 
            CPU, HDD, Ram</label>
```

Script:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function () {
                    if ($(this).prop("checked") == true) {
                        alert("Checkbox is checked.");
                    } else if ($(this).prop("checked") == false) {
                        alert("Checkbox is unchecked.");
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
```